# Print formula to print a hyperlink target in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm setting up an excel spreadsheet with multiple documents hyperlinked in. The idea is that the employee will look through the spreadsheet and find the document needed. Setting up the hyperlink to pull it up is simple, but what I want is a button/method that when clicked, it prints to the default printer or opens up the option to print. I've been hitting multiple dead ends trying to get this done....anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You could just pop `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show` into a macro and have the button call that macro. You can't show the print dialog from a formula though.

Comment: @JNevill that opens the print dialog for the excel document, right? I think OP wants to open the print dialog to print the linked documento

Comment: What kind of documents are linked on the spreadsheet? Word docs, PDF files?

Comment: PDF doc. I've tried adding some macros to the doc when I insert it into the spreadsheet as an icon, but clicking it only gets the spreadsheet printed out. Is there a way to go one step further and have it only print the doc?